# Python selenium is not showing table content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-table

I'm starting to use Python selenium library for web scraping.

I'm trying to take the values from a table in a web page. This page is accesible with a user and password, so that's why I can't show the page.

The content of the table can be changed whenever I change the date. My code is first changing the dates with

```
driver.find_element_by_name('daterangepicker_start').clear()
driver.find_element_by_name('daterangepicker_start').send_keys(date)
driver.find_element_by_name('daterangepicker_end').clear()
driver.find_element_by_name('daterangepicker_end').send_keys(date2)
```

The date is succesfully changed and the table is shown.

Then I try to get the table with

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id=table_id]")
tbody = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
rows = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
```

The problem is that I know that there are several rows, but the variable `rows` is empty.

There are no rows before changing the date, so it seems that the `driver`is not aware of this change!

The code has no exception, but it's not showing the content.

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Do you use selenium to log in before you reach the page with your table? Because then it would be useful to add some time.sleep(5), so the page can load until you search for the table.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Very easy solution.